# Handling multiple threads in a Client-Server architecture for File synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I had to implement a Client-Server application in Java that automatically updates txt files in a Server directory depending on changes in the files in the Client side, for a homework assignment (had to, because I'm past the deadline).

I have a package that handles the changes in the files correctly, but I'm stumped about how to handle the changes in multiple files. My approach was using separate threads for each file in the client directory and using corresponding threads in the server directory for the same cause. This approach works for a single file, but not for multiples.

The code below is on the client side and calls a file's thread's checkfilestate method to handle the updates.

```
while(true){
    for (Map.Entry<String, SynchronisedFile> entry : fileList.entrySet())  {  
    try {
        System.err.println("SyncTest: calling fromFile.CheckFileState()");
        sstt.start();
        entry.getValue().CheckFileState();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    }
```

And on the server side, if I start a single thread using:

```
    Thread sstt = new Thread(new SyncThreadServer(sfileList.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue(),clientSocket));
    sstt.start();
```

It works as expected. But if I start the serverside threads at the same time (which contains methods for decoding the Json messages from the input stream) using:

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, SynchronisedFile> entry : sfileList.entrySet())
    {
        Thread sstt = new Thread(new SyncThreadServer(entry.getValue(),clientSocket));
        sstt.setName(entry.getKey());
    }
```

Threads of other files start reading JSON messages intended for other threads from the input stream. I'd like to be able to stop the serverside loop from starting the next thread, at least until the checkFile method is complete for one file/thread. But I still might run into problems after the initial stage, when all the treads are running at the same time. Any solutions on how to handle multiple threads in this case? (All threads use a single socket).

Edit: As I understand, this has to do with synchronization. Threads of other files on the server are accessing the Input stream before the first thread has even finished processing the inputs meant for it. This is the code of the server thread below. I need to somehow block the other threads from accessing the input stream before the first one has finished using it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class SyncThreadServer implements Runnable {

SynchronisedFile toFile; // this would be on the Server //Is an instance of the syncfile class, should be able to proc insts
Socket clientSocket;
public SyncThreadServer(SynchronisedFile tf, Socket aClientSocket){
    toFile=tf;
    clientSocket = aClientSocket;

    }

@Override
public void run() {
    Instruction inst = null;
    InstructionFactory instFact=new InstructionFactory();      

    while(true){
 {    
        try{

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        String smsg = in.readUTF();

        Instruction receivedInst = instFact.FromJSON(smsg);
        System.err.println(smsg);
            // The Server processes the instruction
            toFile.ProcessInstruction(receivedInst);
            //if(receivedInst.Type().equals("EndUpdate")){
              //      out.writeUTF("NEXT"); //TODO: Change to Json
                //    out.flush();}
            //else
            //{
                out.writeUTF("GO"); //TODO: Change to Json
                out.flush();
            }
            //}

         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1); // just die at the first sign of trouble
        } catch (BlockUnavailableException e) {
            // The server does not have the bytes referred to by the block hash.
            try {

                DataOutputStream out2 = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                out2.writeUTF("NGO");   //TODO: Change to Json
                out2.flush();


                String msg2 = in2.readUTF();
                Instruction receivedInst2 = instFact.FromJSON(msg2);
                toFile.ProcessInstruction(receivedInst2);
                if(receivedInst2.Type().equals("EndUpdate")){
                    out2.writeUTF("NEXT"); //TODO: Change to Json
                    out2.flush();}
            else
            {
                out2.writeUTF("GO"); //TODO: Change to Json
                out2.flush();
            }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            } catch (BlockUnavailableException e1) {
                assert(false); // a NewBlockInstruction can never throw this exception
            }
        }
       // } //And here
    }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Happy to give more information, if need be.

Comment: From a design point I am wondering why you are "coupling" client and server so "closely": why does the client need to know how many threads the server is using; it even has to create them?! Your **server** should offer a service to update file(s); and how the server is implementing this service (using one or more threads) should be completely hidden from users of that service.

Comment: start the thread..!!

Comment: SynchronisedFile is a class (supplied to us for this task) which has the checkfilestate() functionality for this object. On the server, an object of this class handles the JSON instruction parsing, and on the client side, it handles creating those instructions. Also because of the nature of the Client and Server thread classes, I need to pass the syncfile object as an argument. As for your question, I'm not experienced enough to offer abstraction yet. So, using a closely coupled approach.

Comment: Add the missing Thread#start() statement. Sorry about that.